# Using same array for moving average in C

Tags: c, moving-average

I would like to use a moving average on 2 vars using the same array.
My problem is that I am using the array RAW_RESULT for both of them, and the value of "averege_value1" gets on the average of averege_value2.
What is the proper way to deal with such a case?

Thanks

```
UINT64 averege_value1,averege_value2;
UINT64 RAW_RESULT[2];

UINT64 MovingAverage(UINT64 average_value[] , UINT32 counter){

        average_value[0] =  average_value[0] + (average_value[1] / (UINT64)counter) - (average_value[0] / (UINT64)counter);
        return average_value[0];
}

int main() {
    int counter = 0;

    RAW_RESULT[1] = somevalue1;
    averege_value1 = MovingAverage(move_avg_tti.RAW_RESULT, counter);

    RAW_RESULT[1] = somevalue2;
    averege_value2 = MovingAverage(move_avg_tti.RAW_RESULT, counter);

    counter++;
    return 0
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand *what* you are trying to do, let alone *how*.

Comment: I am trying to do an average on 2 number on parallel,
for example: averege_value1 = [10,10,20,20....] , averege_value1 = [15,15,40,20....]
lets say i have another 1000000000 values in each of them, therefore I dont want to pass the max value of UINT64,

Comment: this doesn't compile ...

Comment: What is your input data? What are you expecting as output?

Comment: I can't do regular averaging of (A1+A2......+An)/n because the numerator will exceed UINT64

Comment: Well, now it appears to be an XY-problem.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're saying you want to sum the first n elements, then divide by n, repetitively.  `uint64 avg; for(uint64 i = 0; i < len(ara); i ++) { avg = (avg + ara[i]) / 2; }` If you do that you'll have loss of accuracy, because at each step you'll loose the decimal places.

Comment: I think this is an example that might help you out https://gist.github.com/bmccormack/d12f4bf0c96423d03f82

Comment: Are you saying that there is an array of `struct` and you want to get moving averages of two of the variables in that `struct`? `struct { UINT64 a[2]; }` perhaps? I assume you mean cumulative moving average? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average